# uWSGI won't start via Upstart, but starts ok from the console

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, upstart, uwsgi

I'm trying to make uWSGI [run on boot](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Upstart.html#running-uwsgi-via-upstart) using Upstart on a Vagrant box. So I've created `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf` with the following contents:

```
# simple uWSGI script

description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]            
respawn            
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /vagrant/share/uwsgi.ini
```

It starts ok if I run `start uwsgi` from the console, but not on boot time. `/var/log/syslog` contains the following:

```
kernel: [    6.234112] init: uwsgi main process (1017) terminated with status 1
kernel: [    6.234122] init: uwsgi main process ended, respawning
...
kernel: [    6.586285] init: uwsgi respawning too fast, stopped
```

What can be the issue?